# Xstream ConversionException for Wrong Input String

Tags: json, exception, xstream

I'm using xStream to some JSON. I've used xstream quite extensively over the years. However this issue has me stumped.

I'm getting the following ConversionException...

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: For input string: ".232017E.232017E44"
---- Debugging information ----
message             : For input string: ".232017E.232017E44"
cause-exception     : java.lang.NumberFormatException
cause-message       : For input string: ".232017E.232017E44"
class               : java.sql.Timestamp
required-type       : java.sql.Timestamp
converter-type      : com.etepstudios.xstream.XStreamTimestampConverter
line number         : -1
class[1]            : com.pbp.bookacall.dataobjects.AppleReceipt
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : com.pbp.bookacall.dataobjects.AppleReceiptCollection
version             : 1.4.10
-------------------------------
at com.etepstudios.xstream.XStreamTimestampConverter.unmarshal(XStreamTimestampConverter.java:87)
```

In my XStreamTimestampConverter class I print out the value that is attempting to be converted.. Which turns out to be the following...

```
XStreamTimestampConverter value = 2017-08-05 23:44:23.GMT
```

Here is the unmarshal function in my converter...

```
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) 
{
    Timestamp theTimestamp;
    Date theDate;

    String value = reader.getValue ();

    try 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Z");

        theDate = formatter.parse(value);

        theTimestamp = new Timestamp (theDate.getTime());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println ("XStreamTimestampConverter value = " + value);

        throw new ConversionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return theTimestamp;
}
```

Any idea where this odd string is coming from? It does not exist anywhere in my JSON. Does xstream have some odd .[num]E.[num]E[num] notation for something? These numbers can change as I run this each time. Also I get an For input string: "" on occasion too. Yet the value is similar to the what is above. It's like it's randomly getting odd values for somewhere.

The data source is from Apple's In-App Purchase /VerifyReceipt web call. The system works just fine some times but then others it does not. It's also important to note that in this very case it parsed 100s of other Date/Timestamp strings using this converter. It just get's confused. Perhaps due to the size of the data?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was going on here. The unmarshal function above is not exactly as I have it in code...

The SimpleDateFormat formatter is actually set in the class rather than in the unmarshal method. Therefore if Xstream holds on to an instance of my converter and the unmarshal is called across multiple threads then it is possible that the formatter can get confused since it is the same object.

That's my only guess at this point as moving the formatter initialization into the method solved the issue. I would say SimpleDateFormatter is not thread safe?

It was the just the sheer about of data and the number of times it was concurrently being called that exposed this issue. Just a tip for anyone else in case this happens to them.